# Expandable List View Bottom Divider

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, expandablelistview, android-xml

I've an expandable list view like this one in the image:

[image]

When I expand a child I'd like to mantain the bottom divider,
that insted is missing. What's the simplest way to do that?
Child Divider color is trasparent because I don't want the
top divider line as well, just the bottom one.

Here my layouts:

**Expandable List View:**

```
<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/expandable_list_test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:childDivider="@android:color/transparent">
</ExpandableListView>
```

**Expandable Group Row:**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview_test"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/test" >
</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview_description_group"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageview_test"
    android:textSize="16sp" >
</TextView>
```

**Expandable Row:**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview_description_child"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:textSize="14sp" >
</TextView>
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can get this working by adding a footer in your child view item and then handling it your way in your `getChildView()` method called in your custom adapter.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_description_child"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:textSize="14sp" >
    </TextView>
    <View
       android:id="@+id/divider_description_child"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="1dp"
       android:background="#FF0000" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

And then in your getChildView()

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ....

    if(childPosition == (childrenItems.size() - 1))
    {
        // set your divider visibility as VISIBLIE
    }else
    {
        // set your divider visibility as GONE
    }
    ....

}
```

Comment: Could `if(childPosition == (childrenItems.size() - 1))` be replaced by `isLastChild`?